# compute $\sum \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2}$ by using fourier series of sinx

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $$\sin x=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\cdot\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\cos (2nx)}{4n^2-1}$$

be fourier series on $x\in\left[ 0,\pi\right]$. Show that

$$\frac{1}{1^2\cdot3^2}+\frac{1}{3^2\cdot5^2}+\frac{1}{5^2\cdot7^2}+...=\frac{\pi^2-8}{16}$$

I try to solve with partial fraction  $$\frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\boxed{\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n-1}}+\boxed{\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}}\right)$$

I think 1st box is telescopic series  and using the sinx series to calculate the 2nd box.

I can solve the value of series with  other technique e.g. $\zeta(2)$, Parseval's Identity, etc, But I would like to solve the series with fourier series of $\sin x$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Parseval's theorem would be useful.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You're fast.

Comment: Can I solve without Parseval's identity? 
The problem is given only fourier series of sinx and prove the statement by the given, Can I prove without the identity?

Comment: I have solved with Parseval' identity.
I consider $f:=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\sin(\frac{x}{2})$ and use the identity to solve but I think It can solved only using fourier series of sinx.

Comment: Parseval's theorem is using Fourier series. Modulo constants, you want to evaluate the sum of the squares of the Fourier coefficients. That's precisely what Parseval's theorem is about.

Comment: Since you did not accept nor upvoted my answer, I realize that it wasn't helpful to you. I apologize for that. Hence I deleted it.